# which would be the best way to implement movement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, So my slider should only move in response to the user pressing the mouse button down on the thumb knob itself. The thumb knob should then move along the track in response to the user moving the mouse and should stop moving when the user releases the mouse.

This is my code so far but I am not positive if i should use Document.onkeydown or would i use a different function to implement the moving of my grey slider inside the limited box that is given?

```
     <style>
     div.parent-item {

     width: 400px;
     height:50px;
     margin: 25px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;

        }

      #knob {
      width: 50px;
      height:50px;
       background-color: grey;
      margin-left: 25%;

          }

             }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <h1>in chrome</h1>

          <form action="horizontal_form.asp">
       <input type="radio" name="angle" value="Horizontal" checked>Horizontal
       <form action="vertical_form">
     <input type="radio" name="angle" value="Vertical">Vertical
           </form>
      <div class="parent-item">

         <div id="knob"></div>
        </div>
```

View of my code - http://jsfiddle.net/xvrhumtc/

but if anyone could suggest anything it would be greatly appreciated!

Please don't close my question :)

Comment: Your jsfiddle link does not work - it links to the main page of jsfiddle. It sounds like what you're looking for is very similar to an input slider. If so, check out [slider implementations](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_form_sliders.asp) for a little inspiration. Otherwise, fix the link!

Comment: If HTML5 is an option, you could consider using a standard input[type=range]\

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xvrhumtc/

Comment: I fixed the link, so it should work now